# shareReplay changes the order

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I wrote some Observable from Array [1, 2, 3, 4, 5] which logs at each iteration. So the output I am getting is : 1,2,3,4,5 like the way it should be.

When I am adding  shareReplay(2) I am getting the last two iteration - 4,5. It make no sense to me.. I was expecting to get 1,2 as an output.

```
numbers$: Observable<number> = from([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]);

ngOnInit() {
this.numbers$.pipe(
  shareReplay(2),
  refCount()
).subscribe(data => console.log(data));
```

}

I got it on stackBlitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/hello-angular-6-yb387t?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Comment: `shareReplay(2)` is caching always the last two emissions from the source Observable which is 4,5

Comment: But isn't the idea of shareReplay operator is to cache the call? How can he cache if he is taking the last calls?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "cache the call". If you want to cache the entire sequence you can use it without any parameter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ShareReplay` always replays the last two emitted value from the observable. If you need the first two, you should use `take(2)` instead. If you also need the replay functionality, you can still use `shareReplay`:

```
this.numbers$.pipe(
  take(2),
  shareReplay()
).subscribe(data => console.log(data));
```

One more thing: when you use `shareReplay` you don't need to use `refCount` as it is already used by `shareReplay` under the hood. There is a very good explanation for this [here](https://blog.angularindepth.com/rxjs-how-to-use-refcount-73a0c6619a4e).

Comment: But isn't  the idea of shareReplay operator is to cache the call? How can he cache if he is taking the last calls?

Comment: It does cache, yes. If you use it without arguments, it will replay the whole observable. With the parameter, it will only replay the last _n_ emissions. Basically when you cache, you want to store the latest value, so I think this logic fits in well.